# PostgreSQL 9.4 - Allow access from PHP

Tags: postgresql, php, postgresql-9.4

I would like to configure PostgreSQL 9.4 to allow connections from database users with passwords from PHP on both the command line and through Apache on a CentOS 6.6 box.  I installed PostgreSQL with yum and the only configuration changes I have made are in the `pg_hba.conf` file:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS          METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all         all                               md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all         all         ::1/128               md5
```

I have a test database called `test` and a user named `psql` with the password of `psql`. Logging in on the command line works fine:

```
psql -U psql -W test  
Password for user psql:   
psql (9.4.5) Type "help" for help.

test=>
```

The privileges are:

[image]

My PHP code is:

```
<?php
$user = 'psql';
$pass = 'psql';
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('pgsql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
    foreach($dbh->query('SELECT * from test') as $row) {
        print_r($row);
    }
    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
    die();
}
```

Yields the error:

> Error!: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "psql"

I tried using **trust** as well, but that didn't work either, and I would like to know how to allow access for database users with passwords.  I would like to avoid using **ident**.

Could you tell me what's wrong?

Comment: On the command line test, you are connecting to the socket, whereas the PHP code tries to connect via tcp.  Does the PHP app reside on the DB server?  The error message suggests a different state of the `ph_hba.conf` from what you show above.

Comment: When you made the changes to the `pg_hba.conf`, did you run `service postgresql-9.4 reload` to actually apply the changes?

Comment: @deszo - Thank you for the tip.  The issue was that I was modifying /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf, instead of /var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/pg_hba.conf.